# Run jar file on startup as root without password

Tags: linux, root, startup

I developed a jar file I would like to run in all *nix platforms. I want to run the jar file on every restart with the root privileges without prompting any password. I googled for the solution but it shows I should write a script and add to folders. But I should be able to write the script from the jar itself. Is it possible to perform such operations, if not what are the other solutions?

Comment: If a solution writes about 'add to folders' I seriously doubt it was written by a competent Unix administrator.

Comment: @Anthon As I said earlier I am new to Linux. Problem here is, the jar file which should run, should also be used to write scripts to run as root without password and run at start up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot speak for all *nix platforms, but on most Linuxes and BSDs, `cron` has the (non-posix) `@reboot` special schedule.

```
# crontab -e
<editor>
@reboot /path/to/java-wrapper-that-runs-the-jar
```

If you cannot be bothered to put your java command line in a one-line shell script, you can conceivably try

```
@reboot /path/to/java -jar /path/to/jar
```

but this may lack environment such as JAVA_HOME etc.

The cron approach is likely more portable than using `/etc/rc.local` which I believe to be a Linuxism (though I may be wrong).

Comment: Here starts my problem, the jar file I should run should write the wrapper for it. And will cron be installed in every Linuxes and BSDs?

Comment: @Parthe on the vast majority anyway. There _might_ be some obscure system that does not have cron but I very much doubt it. Are you also targeting embedded systems?

Comment: If you target non-POSIX platforms, you will have to find individual "run at boot" solutions, I expect, and I cannot think of examples that are pertinent these days. Cron is POSIX compliant (although `@reboot` is not, as stated). Concerning the "jar file writing the wrapper", whatever that means, it does sound suspiciously like a chicken-and-egg problem. If it is an important point, you should update your question to elaborate.

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is a traditional BSD feature that many but not all other init systems also support.

Comment: @terdon No only *nix based computers

Comment: @FelixFrank I am new to *nix based systems. I will research on POSIX and non POSIX systems. Regarding the "jar file writing the wrapper", In windows based systems, I added a registry key when installing my jar which helped in running at boot. I am looking for something similar to that.

Comment: @Gilles Something similar to Windows registry should be present in all *nix based systems right? So can we find that and do something with that?

Comment: @Parthe The Windows registry is very much a Windows thing. The Linux equivalent is roughly `/etc` for system-wide stuff and dot files for user-specific stuff. A file in `/etc` is the normal Unix way of doing things — it's as close to your Windows registry as it gets.

Comment: @Gilles Let's say I install my jar in root status and write `java -jar myjar.jar` in rc.d in status 3(multiuser), will the jar run on boot even if I run with user access?